# How to add a KML vector from a string variable

Tags: openlayers, kml

I have a variable that contains KML data how so I tried to do some research and come up with this code

```
var kmlString = result;

var features = new ol.format.KML().readFeatures(kmlString, {
    dataProjection: 'EPSG:4326'
    });

var KMLvectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({});

var KMLvector = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: KMLvectorSource,
    visible: true
    });

KMLvectorSource.addFeature(features);
map.addLayer(KMLvector);
```

but I don't know why it doesn't work, I get error message: `a.addEventListener is not a function`

My KML string is:

`<Polygon><extrude>0</extrude><tessellate>0</tessellate><alti‌​tudeMode>relativeToG‌​round</altitudeMode>‌​<outerBoundaryIs><Li‌​nearRing><coordinate‌​s> list of coordinates </coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon>`

Answer (score 1):

because of `KMLvectorSource.addFeature(features);`

`addFeature` for single feature but features is an array though its length is 1.
So, use `addFeatures` instead or change `features` to `features[0]`

Comment: it doesn't work   error Code: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Comment: check this out: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YQZPGd

Comment: I tried that code but there is a error  Cannot read property 'ol_uid' of undefined

Comment: this is my kml string 
<Polygon><extrude>0</extrude><tessellate>0</tessellate><altitudeMode>relativeToGround</altitudeMode><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>
list of coordinates 

</coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon>
 is this a correct format

Comment: try drag and drop the file into this example: http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/drag-and-drop.html
+ don't they have a <kml> tag? at least it needs <kml> and <Placemark> tag

Comment: its from database i get it from geometry of a city  
i think something is wrong with my kml file because it doesn't show anything when i try it to drag and drop

Comment: and i found some weird thing. when I copy your string (Li‌​nearRing) into codepen, the character `i` seems not normal string.

Comment: there is really something wrong with the kml. i will look in to it in my database. thanks you so much for helping me find my problem.